# Tape Supplier in Canada

Tags: untagged

I'm not sure if it's kosher to ask.. but where can one purchase good quality / well priced backup tapes within Canada, online? I'm asking because my current vendor, DataWrite, has sent me bad tapes for the 3rd time in a row.

I have no idea where they get their product but when I put an order in for 20 tapes and 2 cleaning tapes and I have to call them up 4 times over the next 2 weeks, I expect those tapes to work. Well, like I said, this is the 3rd batch that I'm sending back and we've been dealing with them exclusively for well over 5 years so I thought I'd ask the pool of knowledge. I'm currently looking for DAT72 tapes but soon will be looking for LTO-3 and LTO-4.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that it is the tapes and not the drive? When they need a proper service cleaning they can often get a lot more picky over tapes.

Comment: I have older tapes, many of them, which I overwrite after they reach 3 months of age. These older tapes work each and every time I use them. I do run regular cleanings, usually once every 3 days. If it were the drive I would expect the older tapes to exhibit the same issues as the new tapes but they do not. Bottom line: the old tapes work every single time; the new tapes fail every single time. It would seem to be pretty solid evidence.

Answer (score 5):

Have used CDW and had no issues.  Good selection but price could be a bit better.  But they always work!

Comment: I'll check their prices. At this point I don't mind paying a slightly elevated price for prompt service and reliability. Thank you for your suggestion. I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: +1. I've purchased LTO2 tapes from CDW for the past 5 years and have yet to have a problem.

Comment: +1 for CDW. Haven't bought tapes from them yet, but everything else has been excellent.

Answer (score 0):

We buy our tapes through Dell for the last 4 or 5 years; never had an issue (deployed in dozens of environments) and we do regular test restores, compression/encryption, etc. with both Backup Exec (all versions) and NT/Windows Backup.